# Does travel to African countries have a negative impact on Schengen & UK visa applications?

Tags: uk, schengen-visas, standard-visitor-visas

I travelled to West Africa in 2014. Now I would like to visit European countries (UK and Belgium) to attend conferences. Are passport stamps from African countries a problem while applying for those visas?

Comment: Why would it? (Any why is this question tagged "usa"?)

Comment: @HenningMakholm - i would like to hear USA people suggestion as well...

Comment: @pavankumar The tags are supposed to be a summary of what the question is about, for indexing purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Generally any travel experience at all (except maybe to North Korea, known terrorist training hot spots, or areas suffering outbreak of communicable diseases like Ebola) is viewed more favorably than no travel experience at all.

That said the kind of travel experience that garners significant favor with visa officers is travel to countries that are more affluent and advanced than yours. Thus for an Indian, traveling to West Africa will give you very little benefit in the eyes of a Western European (American, Asian, Australian) visa officer.

Unfortunately the truth is Africa travel experience typically does not enhance credibility with visa officers anywhere.

> Are passport stamps from African countries a problem while applying
>   for those visas?

Why should they be? There are many Africans who even get visas to visit the countries you mention.

Comment: I'm not so sure it won't help too much...I guess there's always the chance of suspicion they're forged stamps? But generally I'd think being able to fly from India to Africa several times shows a certain level of affluence and interest in travelling for legitimate reasons that someone who plans to overstay would not have

Comment: @theotherone Where did **several times** come into play? I did not see him say he flew to West Africa several times. In any case even if it did, in my opinion it won't help much.I had Ghanaian friends fly to Dubai and South Africa several times before attempting a USA/UK or Schengen visa which were not successful..

Answer (score -1):

You don't have any bad impact for Schengen Countries having an African visa on your passport. Absolutely NOT

Comment: Please add some more info/references. Suppose someone else comes along and writes an answer (also without backing it up): "Yes, getting a visa will be much more difficult. Prepare for a minimum waiting time of two months". Then which of the two is the correct answer?